# How to pass the yaml property to Uber Cadence cronSchedule annotation

Tags: java, cadence-workflow, temporal-workflow, uber-cadence

I am new to uber Cadence and trying to write a cron scheduled task. Cadence provided a cronSchedule annotation (find an example online) which takes a cron expression string for the method to be triggered at specific time. However, I want this cron expression to be loaded according to what we set in the yml file. Is there any way to do it?
I currently only found this @cronSchedule annotation way to do it. I also found there is a WorkflowOption that I can set the cronSchedule. However, don't know how to use it to trigger the method. Below is the current code.

```
public interface CronTask {


    @WorkflowMethod(
            workflowId = CRON_WORKFLOW_ID,
            taskList = TASK_LIST,
            executionStartToCloseTimeoutSeconds = 30,
            workflowIdReusePolicy = WorkflowIdReusePolicy.TerminateIfRunning
    )
    @CronSchedule("*/1 * * * *") 
    void kickOff(String name);
}
```

If there is no way to achieve this. Does anyone know if we can simply replace this `@CronSchedule` annotation with spring `@Scheduled`? Will the annotation `WorkflowMethod` still work as expected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In [Temporal](https://docs.temporal.io/docs/java/distributed-cron) you can do it through WorkflowOptions:

```java
    WorkflowOptions workflowOptions =
        WorkflowOptions.newBuilder()
            .setWorkflowId(WORKFLOW_ID)
            .setTaskQueue(TASK_QUEUE)
            .setCronSchedule("* * * * *")
            .setWorkflowExecutionTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(3))
            .setWorkflowRunTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(1))
            .build();

    // Create the workflow client stub. It is used to start our workflow execution.
    GreetingWorkflow workflow = client.newWorkflowStub(GreetingWorkflow.class, workflowOptions);
```

I believe Cadence has a similar capability.